# Self created library with dependency to another self created library

Tags: android, android-studio, dependencies, android-gradle-plugin

I am trying to build an app which is composed out of separate library projects.

To do this, I'm trying to make a **proof of concept** which is supposed to be as following:
[image]

I tried to keep the project as simple as possible. The projects contents do not matter!
All that matters is the **dependencies** between the projects!

The **result** should be that `MainProject` will print out `Something Another String!`

I have tried all from **.JAR** files to **.AAR** files, but the best I got was
with the dependency in red. I added the `StringExtender.aar` file to `StringReturner`, and then the `StringReturner.aar` file to the `MainProject`.

When I do this I get the following Exception:

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/example/erik/stringextender/StringExtender;

What is the right way to setup a simple proof of concept like this? I can't seem to find anything related to a library project having a dependency. It's all 1 level deep!

Any help is welcome!

**EDIT SHOWING GRADLE BUILD FILES**
**`StringReturner`:**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.1'
    compile project(':StringExtender-lib-debug')
}
```

**MainProject:**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.erik.erikpoc10"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.1'
    compile project(':StringReturnerLib-debug')
}
```

Comment: @MsYvetteǝʇʇǝʌʎsW Done!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following tutorial - [Creating libraries for Android applications](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidLibraryProjects/article.html#librarymodules)

See a working example project on my [Github](https://github.com/Zarathes/NestedLibraries)

The most important steps taken were:

- 8.3. Create library module.
- 8.6. Define dependency to the library project.

Do not forget to import the library class you want to use, for example:
In MainProject: import com.example.stringreturner.StringReturner.
 In StringReturner: import com.example.stringreturner.StringExtender.

The info below is based on the image you provided:

The library methods are not static so don't forget to make an actual object.
So StringReturner should make a StringExtender object, And MainProject should make a StringReturner object first!

And finally, I think it's a typo but both libraries have the class StringReturner. This will not work in the StringReturner library for obvious reasons.

I should also note that I used Android Studio 2.0 and I did not touch .JAR files nor .AAR files. I merely created two library modules and one app. Then configured the Project Structure -> Dependencies by adding Module Dependencies.